# Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I've just downloaded phpMyAdmin 4.8.1 via composer on my local machine (windows) after installing my lamp stack apache 2.4, php 7.2, mariadb 10.3, but when I login using root (without password) it gave me this error on Chrome 67:

http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

`Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin.`

I've already set the blowfish secret and comment `//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;`

I've already cleared my browser cache. This is a local development not production box. If I use `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';` I can login successfully but when i use the `cookie` it gave me that error so I can't proceed to login.

Comment: This affects some users and has been noted in the bug tracker: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14184. For some users, pressing the "Go" button a second time works.

Comment: Aw, I'm glad it's a bug, not a feature @IsaacBennetch ^_^" and I've resorted to use HeidiSQL portable at the moment since I'm on Windows

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. Thanks to you, I was able to fix it. You just have to add this line to your `config.inc.php`:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

For context, this goes below the following condition:

```
if($wampConf['SupportMariaDB'] =='on')
```

[config.inc.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHdfa.png)

Comment: You shouldn't post screenshots of code on Stack Overflow. Since your post otherwise provides an answer that isn't reliant on the screenshot, it _probably_ won't get deleted. But in order to provide context, I recommend that you copy the code into your answer and format it. That should achieve the same effect, without relying on a screenshot.

Comment: (To note, the reason why screenshots of code are discouraged is because a) they're hard to read, b) they're hard to copy/paste from, and c) they prevent the code from being indexed by the search engine, thus making relevant answers harder to discover.)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by resetting the cache of the page. Hold down the `shift key` on your keyboard and click on the `refresh icon` close to the address bar on your Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line command at end of `config.inc.php` inside `phpmyadmin` directory

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I deployed phpMyAdmin using Helm. The problem arose because I initially used bitnami/phpmyadmin. It seems they have specific configurations related to their Helm chart. However, when I created my own Helm chart using the official phpMyAdmin container image, the issue was resolved without encountering that error.

One thing to note is to be mindful of environment variables, as some are mandatory, such as:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD (required)
PMA_HOST (preferably added instead of setting an arbitrary server so the host is not unknown).
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).